# Hadoop YARN: AclSubmitApps in fair-scheduler.xml takes no effect?

Tags: hadoop, acl, hadoop-yarn

What I intend to do is to limit the user or group who can send tasks to `testmonitor` queue.

After I set the `AclSubmitApps` as below, I can still submit a hive task, whose queue is set to `testmonitor` via `set mapred.job.queue.name=root.testmonitor;`, in user `monitor:monitor`. I can assure that my fair-scheduler.xml is reloaded by yarn (By changing the `maxRunningApps` and can see the change in hadoop monitor webpage).

I can see no essential difference between my `fair-scheduler.xml` and the example given by the  [official document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html). Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

My fair-scheduler.xml

```
<allocations>
  <queue name="default">
    <minResources>100000 mb,64vcores</minResources>
    <maxResources>12000000 mb,720vcores</maxResources>
    <maxRunningApps>50</maxRunningApps>
    <weight>1.0</weight>
    <schedulingPolicy>fifo</schedulingPolicy>
    <minSharePreemptionTimeout>300</minSharePreemptionTimeout>
  </queue>

  <queue name="testmonitor">
    <minResources>12000000 mb, 600vcores</minResources>
    <maxResources>20000000 mb, 720vcores</maxResources>
    <maxRunningApps>5</maxRunningApps>
    <weight>2.0</weight>
    <schedulingPolicy>fair</schedulingPolicy>
    <minSharePreemptionTimeout>300</minSharePreemptionTimeout>
    <aclSubmitApps>testmonitor</aclSubmitApps>
  </queue>

  <userMaxAppsDefault>50</userMaxAppsDefault>
  <fairSharePreemptionTimeout>6000</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>
  <defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>fifo</defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>
</allocations>
```

Monitoring on the running task:
[image]

Example on official document about fair scheduler:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
  <queue name="sample_queue">
    <minResources>10000 mb,0vcores</minResources>
    <maxResources>90000 mb,0vcores</maxResources>
    <maxRunningApps>50</maxRunningApps>
    <weight>2.0</weight>
    <schedulingPolicy>fair</schedulingPolicy>
    <queue name="sample_sub_queue">
      <aclSubmitApps>charlie</aclSubmitApps>
      <minResources>5000 mb,0vcores</minResources>
    </queue>
  </queue>

  <user name="sample_user">
    <maxRunningApps>30</maxRunningApps>
  </user>
  <userMaxAppsDefault>5</userMaxAppsDefault>

  <queuePlacementPolicy>
    <rule name="specified" />
    <rule name="primaryGroup" create="false" />
    <rule name="default" />
  </queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add root queue as parent queue.

```
<queue name="root">
<aclSubmitApps> </aclSubmitApps>
<queue name="queue1">
    <minResources>10000mb,10vcores</minResources>
    <maxResources>30000mb,30vcores</maxResources>
    <maxRunningApps>10</maxRunningApps>
    <weight>2.0</weight>
    <schedulingMode>fair</schedulingMode>
    <aclAdministerApps>User1</aclAdministerApps>
    <aclSubmitApps>User1</aclSubmitApps>
</queue> 
</queue>
```